# CodeEffects Rules Engine - (PHP - Java - Cloud Alternative )

Tags: php, symfony, rule-engine

I am working on a project that using code effects rules engine built with .net framework , trying to migrate to PHP Symfony2 , is there any rules engine alternative for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few weeks of search , i will go with Drools.
Looks like the only possible option can fit the needs for the project
https://www.drools.org/

Comment: Hi, have you connected PHP to Drools ? If yes , how ?